# Why does Yslow suggest I gZip my files?

Tags: gzip, yslow

When I run a page through YSlow, using the Chrome extension, it gives the page an E grade for gzipping, suggesting  'Compress components with gzip', singling out four javascript files.

If I check these files' headers, they all show that they are gZipped:

**Request Header:**
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch

**Response**
Content-Encoding:gzip

What gives? Is it an error by YSlow?

Comment: Sometimes people report that YSlow gives confusing results for resources that should already be gzip compressed. Do you have any public URLs that exhibit this problem?

Comment: What platform are you running YSlow from? FF, C, O, S, bookmarklet, Node, PhantomJS?

Comment: @BrianC Sure. Holding page [here](http://missatomicbomb.com/).

Comment: I get an A grade for gzip on the holding page.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Thanks for taking the time. What are you using out of interest? Chrome? Seems to be an issue with the Chrome extension. The Bookmarklet reports an 'A' also. I've had no luck getting the FF extension working.

Comment: Firefox, Firebug, YSlow.

Comment: @Pedr, I'm getting the same results - on a Mac using YSlow in Chrome or Firefox it's showing the main doc and all css/js files as coming over gzip compressed. So does PageSpeed in Firefox/firebug. I also tried running the page through webpagetest.org and it too found compression working: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/130313_EK_3SV/.

Comment: @BrianC Curiouser & curiouser. Thanks for checking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PageSpeed site optimization trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632081/pagespeed-site-optimization-trouble)